# Finding prime numbers in Java

Tags: java, math, primes, prime-factoring

I have got a java code that checks for prime numbers and then it displays them. However, there are some instances when there are no prime numbers (e.g between 14 - 17). In those cases I want a single message to appear. For example `"No primes found"`. I don't know how to add this to my code.

This is my whole class:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Prime {

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public static int lowerBound;
    public static int higherBound;

    public void getInput() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Please enter the lower and upper bound");
        String line1 = input.readLine();
        String line2 = input.readLine();
        int lowInput = Integer.parseInt(line1);
        int highInput = Integer.parseInt(line2);
        lowerBound = lowInput;
        higherBound = highInput;
    }

    public void validatedata() throws IOException {
        do {
            getInput();
            if (lowerBound < 2) {
                System.out.println("Finish");
                break;
            } else if (higherBound < lowerBound) {
                System.out
                        .println("The upper bound should be at least as big as the lower bound.");
            }

        } while (higherBound < lowerBound);

    }

    public void prime_calculation() throws IOException {
        while ((lowerBound >= 2) && (higherBound > lowerBound)) {

            int k;
            for (k = lowerBound; k < higherBound; k++) {
                boolean primecheck = true;
                for (int j = 2; j < k; j++) {
                    if (k % j == 0) {
                        primecheck = false;
                    }
                }
                if (primecheck)
                    System.out.println(k);
            }
            validatedata();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my main void method:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class PrimeUser extends Prime {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
        Prime isprime = new Prime();
        isprime.validatedata();
        isprime.prime_calculation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I like your work, and I know this is your first post but can you display the entire class? I could answer this I just need to see the whole class.

Comment: I would add a boolean variable (lets call it `primesInRange`) outside of the for loop, initialized to false. Then, if the for loop gets to the end with `primecheck` still being true, set `primesInRange` to true by changing the if statement to `if (primecheck) { System.out.println(k); primesInRange = true; }`. Then, if `primesInRange` is still false once all of the numbers have been checked, then no primes have been found and you'll know to print out a message.

Comment: Also, just as a slight optimization, you only need to loop from `j = 2` to `j <= k / 2`. For all numbers, there are no factors larger than `n / 2` so there's no need to check every number smaller than it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test#Java which explains how to determine whether a number is a prime.

And then work over your array of values and keep a flag whether a number is a prime or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if ((lowerBound >= 2) && (higherBound > lowerBound))
{
    int k;
    for (k = lowerBound; k < higherBound; k++)
    {
        primecheck = true;
        for (int j=2; j < k/2; j++) // you dont have to check beyond k/2, since (k/2 + 1) times anything whole number cannot be equal to k
        {
            if (k % j == 0) {
                primecheck = false;
                break; // no need for more iterations of the current number, since you already know it is not a prime
            }
        }
        if (primecheck) {
            primes.add(k);
        }
    }
} else {
    // invalid bounds
    return;
}
if (primes.size() > 0) {
    for (int num : primes) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("No primes exist");
}

// Without an array
boolean y = false;
String x = new String();
if ((lowerBound >= 2) && (higherBound > lowerBound))
{
    int k;
    for (k = lowerBound; k < higherBound; k++)
    {
        primecheck = true;
        for (int j=2; j < k/2; j++) // you dont have to check beyond k/2, since (k/2 + 1) times anything whole number cannot be equal to k
        {
            if (k % j == 0) {
                primecheck = false;
                break; // no need for more iterations of the current number, since you already know it is not a prime
            }
        }
        if (primecheck) {
            x += Integer.toString(k) + "\n";
            y = true; // yes, there exists atleast 1 prime
        }
    }
} else {
    // invalid bounds
    return;
}
if (y == true) {
    System.out.println(x);
} else {
    System.out.println("No primes exist");
}
```

Comment: Hello Vikhyath Reddy,

Thank you for your reply but I don't want to use array. I have pasted my whole code. Could anyone help me please? Thank you

Comment: @Vikhyath Reddy `while ((lowerBound >= 2) && (higherBound > lowerBound))` isn't this equal to `while(true)`?

Comment: Well, what if he gave a negative lowerbound and a higherbound < lowerbound? maybe the check should be lowerbound <= higherbound for a more valid use case.

Comment: @user2901128, you need some way of remembering what you have seen as a prime and what you have not. Because you cannot say if no primes have been found until you go till the very end of the range of numbers you are interested in... and by then you will lose a context of what you have already seen.

Comment: @VikhyathReddy: You are right to check the input, but why are you using a while? Should be if.

Comment: @DanielR, ah! yessir, you are right. my bad. stupid of me for wasting so many processor cycles by doing a while.

Comment: Is there anyway I could do that with just loops without an array? This is a university assignment and the prof. said only loops must be used.

Comment: Yes you can. Maintain a String variable say x just after int k. When you find that a number is prime, append to x. In the sense that, x += Integer.toString(num) + "\n"; Now also keep a flag y that is by default set to true. When you find that a number is not a prime, set that to false. After all your loops, check to see if y is false, if it is then print 'no primes' else print x.

Comment: yeah, the method i mentioned just above your comment uses 2 extra variables, a String x and a boolean y. it does not use an array.

Comment: hmm..can you please paste the code as I am nor sure whether I will be able to do that. Thanks

Comment: @user2901128 please check the code below the comments "//without using an array."

Comment: @user2901128 i just made a few corrections. please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Assumes that 2 and 3 are known primes:
Will find 1 million prime numbers in less than 900 milli sec

public class FindPrime 
    {
        private Integer [] arr_num = new Integer[1000000];

```
    private void arr_init()
    {
        for(int i=0; i< arr_num.length; i++)
        {
            arr_num[i] = i;
        }
    }

    private void find_prime()
    {
        for (int i=3; i<arr_num.length; i++)
        {
            find_prm(arr_num[i]);
        }
    }

    private void find_prm(Integer chk_prm)
    {
        boolean isprime = false;
        if(chk_prm == null)
            return;

        if(chk_prm %2 !=0 )
        {
            double sqrt = Math.sqrt(chk_prm);
            for(Integer k=arr_num[2]; (k!= null) && (k<sqrt + 1)  ; k++)
            {
                if(chk_prm % k == 0)
                {
                    isprime=false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    isprime = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            setNull(chk_prm);
        }
        if(!isprime)
        {
            setNull(chk_prm);
        }
    }

    private void setNull(int num_to_null)
    {
        arr_num [num_to_null] = null;
    }

    private void print_prime()
    {
        for(int i=2; i < arr_num.length; i++)
        {
            if(null != arr_num[i])
            {
                System.out.println(arr_num[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        FindPrime findPrime = new FindPrime();
        findPrime.arr_init();
        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        findPrime.find_prime();
            long diff = System.currentTimeMillis()- timeStart;
        System.out.println("Running time :: " + diff);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to solve the problem. I simply added a counter to count the occurrences
of primes. If the counter equals = 0 then display the message. The code is below. Thanks for your help anyway, guys. If I've got any issue I will post again. Btw, I wonder if anyone can tell me or share any source/webpage or simply any way I can train my algorithm skills in finding solutions ?

the final code here

```
    public void prime_calculation() throws IOException
{   

    while ((lowerBound >= 2) && (higherBound > lowerBound))
    {

        int k;
        int m = 0;
        for (k = lowerBound; k < higherBound; k++)
        {
            boolean primecheck = true;
                for (int j=2; j < k; j++)
                {
                    if (k % j == 0)
                    {
                        primecheck = false;
                    }
                }
                    if (primecheck)
                    {               
                    System.out.println(k);
                    m++;
                    }
        }
        if (m == 0)
            System.out.println("No primes found");
    validatedata();
    }   
}
```

}